# Spring @Value split empty string to a List

Tags: java, spring, list, annotations

I using @Value("#{'${names}'.split(',')}") to loading List from properties file.
But if the value of names in properties file is unset like this

```
names=
```

then Spring will initialize a list with size 1, not size 0, and the only element in this list is a empty string, that's weird.

I want to know is this a bug, or Im using it wrong? Im using spring 3.2.3 btw.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not bug of spring,is is a defect of method `split` in `String` class,example:

```
"".split(",");
```

the result length is 1,and contain a empty string;

Comment: Thank you so much! What's the elegant way to avoid this, then?

Comment: Why is it a defect?

Comment: @Wuaner you can use The `Splitter` in Guava Library to omit empty item,just like : `Iterable<String> split = Splitter.on(",").omitEmptyStrings().split("");
        String[] strings = Iterables.toArray(split, String.class);`

Answer (score 0):

Other solution if you don't want to use external libraries is to use elvis expression. 
Maybe not very elegant but works.

```
@Value("#{'${names}'.empty?(new java.util.ArrayList()):'${names}'.split(',')}")
```